# How to set the NDK path for Android 2.2.2

Tags: android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

When I build my ndk project,all is ok,but when run it,the Android monitor shows **W/linker: xxxxx.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x9a30**.I don't know whether it is because of the ndk build version or not,and I even don't know how to set ndk-build version (such as android-ndk-r10e) for my project.
My Android studio is 2.2.2 ,and current ndk is ndk-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

self-answering,the log of 'xxxxx.so: unused DT entry' is indifferent，and if  you want to change your ndk version,you can choose your project ,right click to choose the option of open module settings,select SDK location，edit the Android NDK location，and then operate the menu to choose build - Refresh Linked C++ Projects,and Rebuild your project.